# как корректно получить ответ от xhr

Tags: php, массивы, xmlhttprequest, xhr

отправляю через XMLHttpRequest запрос на другую страницу с обработчиком php, где php скрипт обходит массив и после каждой иттерации выдает текст и в конце фразу `Over!` Все что выдается с обработчика пишется в консоли после каждой иттерации.

По крайне мере на словах это звучит именно так.

Что я пытался в плане кода:

На стороне сайта:

```
function a(arr){    
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open("POST", "/obrabotka.php",false);
    xhr.send(arr);
if (xhr.readyState == 4) {

        // only if "OK"
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log("Не удалось закончить запрос:n" + xhr.statusText);
        }
    }  
    }
```

На стороне обработчика файла obrabotka.php:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);
header("Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);

  foreach ($data as $inch)
  {
    echo "Это тестовая переменная.".$inch." <br>";
   flush();
sleep(1);
  }
 echo "Конец запроса <br>";
```

Массив передается корректный(проверено выводом print_r($data) в файле обработчика. Но единственное что получилось в итоге это - массив отсылается, обработчик думает, на странице ответа обработчика я вижу что он прошелся по массиву и отобразил вывод каждого echo, в консоли пусто, следовательно по xhr ни одного ответа обработано не было. В чем у меня ошибка и как нужно скорректировать мой код чтобы корректно в консоль выводило прогресс обхода массива обработчиком?

Comment: Console.log пишем с маленькой - console

Comment: для начала вам бы не помешало понять, что ответ вэб-сервера отправляется клиенту, когда пхп скрипт завершит свою работу целиком. Второе -  аякс это асинхронный код, если хотите получить ответ, то надо отследить событие изменения статуса. ваш код может вывести в консоль ответ только при синхронном запросе, когда в `open` третьим параметром `false` стоит, иначе ваша строка  `== 4` обрабатывается не дождавшись ответа асинхронного запроса

Comment: Ок, поменял код, добавил на стороне обработчика очистку буфера вывода через flush, но почему-то все равно продолжает сначала ждать всего обхода массива, а лишь потом уже выполнять вывод. Может есть какой-то вариант вывода буфера без ожидания окончания? Т.к. на моем домашнем сервере почему-то flush работал, а на vds с теми же настройками не дает вывода.